# Getting IOError: [Errno Invalid number of channels] -9998 when using mic with PyAudio on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspbian, raspberry-pi2, pyaudio

Bad news, everyone!

I try to use a microphone on my Raspberry Pi through PyAudio but without success. The microphone is connected to a USB sound card.

The microphone works when I go through 'arecord' :

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ arecord -D plughw:0,0 -f cd test2.wav
Recording WAVE 'test2.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 44100 Hz, Stereo
```

However, when I do the test record.py in PyAudio, I got an error. The error is the same for all programs in Python that uses PyAudio :

```
pi@raspberrypi /usr/src/pyaudio/test $ python record.py 
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:957:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) The dmix plugin supports only playback stream
Expression 'parameters->channelCount <= maxChans' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 1438
Expression 'ValidateParameters( inputParameters, hostApi, StreamDirection_In )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 2742
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "record.py", line 26, in <module>
frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyaudio.py", line 747, in open
stream = Stream(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyaudio.py", line 442, in __init__
self._stream = pa.open(**arguments)
IOError: [Errno Invalid number of channels] -9998
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Where is you Python code here?...Need to see it to see where the bug is...

Comment: Hi @KhalilAmmour-خليلعمور , I'm using the test record.py in the folder test of PyAudio. I post the code here: http://pastebin.com/PHyUbhgN I think PyAudio don't recognize my USB sound card.

Comment: Is your RPI upgraded to latest version?

Comment: Yes, my RPI was upgraded today. @KhalilAmmour-خليلعمور

Comment: Di you set your  USB sound card to default in `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` file ?

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. Yes I already put my USB sound card to default. I modified alsa-base.conf for that : `options snd-usb-audio index=0` @KhalilAmmour-خليلعمور

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you have a sound card attached to the Raspberry PI ?
By default you get audio output, but not audio input.
You can check by running

```
alsamixer
```

If you press `F6` you should see your sound cards listed.
If you press `F4` you should see capture devices(if any)

I used a cheap USB soundcard from eBay for testing.

After you have a sound card with an audio input, make sure you configure pyaudio to use the correct sound card index and the number of channels(mine had mono audio input, not stereo).

```
pyaudio.PyAudio().open(format=pyaudio.paInt16,
                        rate=44100,
                        channels=1, #change this to what your sound card supports
                        input_device_index=1, #change this your input sound card index
                        input=True,
                        output=False,
                        frames_per_buffer=1024)
```

You can use pyaudio.PyAudio's instance methods `get_device_count` and `get_device_info_by_index` to get the indices.

Comment: Thank you very much @george-profenza ! I can now record sound through pyaudio with my RPI. Why it's only works when `channels=1` ? Does it means that my USB sound card didn't support stereo ?

Comment: looks like it, mine didn't either. You can see if it's mono or stereo either by selecting your card in ```alsamixer``` and going to ```Capture```, or use ```get_device_info_by_index``` with pyaudio which will print how many channels the device supports: ```pa = pyaudio.PyAudio()
for x in xrange(0,pa.get_device_count()):
    print pa.get_device_info_by_index(x)``` (see the ```maxInputChannels``` property)

Comment: Finally my USB sound card only had 1 input channel. Thank you very much for your answer and your time. @george-profenza