# Dejavu - Audio Fingerprinting in Python - sample rate error

Tags: python, mysql, audio, audio-fingerprinting

I'm trying to get [Dejavu](https://github.com/worldveil/dejavu) to work on raspbian (raspberry pi 3). I'm trying to match audio from microphone input with files in mysql database. I've tested and I'm able to record with pyaudio, however I need to set sample rate = 24000 & CHUNK = 4056. I've pretty much used the default code that comes with Dejavu examples.

When I run the code I get following error: *IOError: [Errno Invalid sample rate] -9997*

Does anyone have any suggestions how to resolve this?

Here is my Python code:

```
import warnings
import json
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

from dejavu import Dejavu
from dejavu.recognize import FileRecognizer, MicrophoneRecognizer

# load config from a JSON file (or anything outputting a python dictionary)
with open("dejavu.cnf.SAMPLE") as f:
    config = json.load(f)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # create a Dejavu instance
    djv = Dejavu(config)

    # Or recognize audio from your microphone for `secs` seconds
    secs = 5
    song = djv.recognize(MicrophoneRecognizer, seconds=secs)
    if song is None:
        print "Nothing recognized -- did you play the song out loud so your mic could hear it? :)"
    else:
        print "From mic with %d seconds we recognized: %s\n" % (secs, song)
```

here is the log from terminal:

```
python exampletest.py
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1022:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
ALSA lib pulse.c:243:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Connection refused

ALSA lib pulse.c:243:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Connection refused

ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1022:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
Expression 'paInvalidSampleRate' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 2048
Expression 'PaAlsaStreamComponent_InitialConfigure( &self->capture, inParams, self->primeBuffers, hwParamsCapture, &realSr )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 2719
Expression 'PaAlsaStream_Configure( stream, inputParameters, outputParameters, sampleRate, framesPerBuffer, &inputLatency, &outputLatency, &hostBufferSizeMode )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 2843
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "exampletest.py", line 26, in <module>
    song = djv.recognize(MicrophoneRecognizer, seconds=secs)
  File "/home/pi/dejavu/dejavu/__init__.py", line 167, in recognize
    return r.recognize(*options, **kwoptions)
  File "/home/pi/dejavu/dejavu/recognize.py", line 103, in recognize
    self.start_recording()
  File "/home/pi/dejavu/dejavu/recognize.py", line 77, in start_recording
    frames_per_buffer=chunksize,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyaudio.py", line 747, in open
    stream = Stream(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyaudio.py", line 442, in __init__
    self._stream = pa.open(**arguments)
IOError: [Errno Invalid sample rate] -9997
```

Comment: Not sure if you fixed this problem already, but I had the same problem a while back. It has to do with the configuration of your sound card. Can you tell me a bit more what you use for audio input and output? Also take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31073667/getting-ioerror-errno-invalid-number-of-channels-9998-when-using-mic-with-py They have quite a similar issue.

Comment: @KevinEtore thanks for tip, I actually got this working by reinstalling everything and making sure I had all dependencies set correctly. I don't know exactly what was causing the issue, but dejavu is working now.

Comment: fantastic this is exactly what i am trying to do i will test it thanks